# Export div content to pdf format

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I used the following code to export div content to pdf format using itextsharp

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Panel1.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
// Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(1000f, 1000f));
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

it shows the following error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Images\logo.png'.`
```

if i hide the logo in desin then it exported to pdf but the alignment are missing. how to correct it.The page i need to export is follows
[image]

Comment: can you show us the html part , which you trying to export ??

I think this link can help you out !
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Web-Page-with-images-to-PDF-using-ITextsharp.aspx

Comment: i edited my question and uploaded the image, please check it

Answer (score 0):

In order to export the content to any pdf file, you need to follow the basic conventions of pdf file, those are given in the appendix G of the following pdf reference,

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
 Firstly install class in Nuget console: Install-Package itextsharp.xmlworker
Then add namespace: using iTextSharp.tool.xml;  





 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //string pdf;
            // pdf = Convert.ToInt32(hidTablEmpCode.ToString()).ToString() + ".Pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
            //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            // var example_html = @"<p>This is <span class="" headline="" style="">some</span> sample  text<span style="">!!!</span></p>";
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(lblMessageDetail.Text);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string imageFilePath2 = Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/GraphicNew.jpg";
                iTextSharp.text.Image jpg3 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath2);
                jpg3.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
                jpg3.ScaleToFit(3530, 835);
                jpg3.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                pdfDoc.Add(jpg3);
            }
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/Bimages/ns5.png";
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
    
            GetEmp();
            string imageURLS = Server.MapPath("~/Emp/Document/") + hidTablEmpCode.Value + "/" + hidSign.Value.ToString();
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURLS);
            jpg2.ScaleToFit(100, 50);
            jpg2.SetAbsolutePosition(370, 530);
            jpg2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    
            pdfDoc.Add(jpg2);
            jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_LEFT;
            jpg.ScaleToFit(100, 50);
            jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(50, 735);
            pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
    
           
    
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
```